# unable to install java using puppetlabs-java

Tags: java, puppet

I am trying to install jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz using puppetlabs-java.below is my puppet code:

```
java::oracle { 'jdk8' :
    ensure  => 'present',
    version => '8',
    java_se => 'jdk',
    oracle_url => 'http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/',
    version_major => '8u171',
    version_minor => 'b11',
    url => 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u171-b11/512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8/jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz',
    url_hash => '512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8',
}
```

error:'rpm --force -iv /tmp/jdk-8u171-linux-x64.rpm' returned 1 instead of one of [0]

error: ./jdk-8u171-linux-x64.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest):

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you try to access that URL for download, you get an unauthorized page.

This is your problem. You must accept oracle's agreement before files download, if you don't, you get this page...

[image]